# 404 Error on yii2 in centmin and nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, yii2, centos, config

I have installed Centmin on my VPS and uploaded my yii2 application to the root of domain I created in it.

Problem is that NGINX doesn't serve PHP files except the index.php and return 404 for all of the files.

here is my domain NGINX config:

```
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name example.com;
            return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
       }

server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  access_log /home/nginx/domains/example.com/log/access.log combined buffer=256k flush=60m;
  error_log /home/nginx/domains/example.com/log/error.log;

  root /home/nginx/domains/example.com/public;

  location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try to change this line `try_files $uri =404;` to `try_files $uri /index.php =404;` ?

Comment: nothing changed. still got 404;

Comment: could you check nginx error log ? check the recent data there and what about the php-fpm config for this site please add it to your question